# Copy a docx to the end of another

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to work with docx documents using java. The principle is simple :

- I have a base template to show data (with text, titles and tables)
- I have data that will fill the template
- I need to produce a final document that will contains the template repeated for each data row

I've succeeded to load the template doc, and I also created the final doc object which contains nothing (from an empty doc containing the styles I want, so I don't loose them). I'm able to change my data fields in the template by going through the paragraphs and tables, but what I can't do is copy the content that has been changed to the final doc.

Basically, this is what I have :

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  finalDoc.removeBodyElement(i);
}
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    //EditableDocX is a subclass of XWPFDocument, for purpose of my project
    EditableDocX document = new EditableDocX("template.docx");  

    replacementMap.put("[field1]", "Content1_"+i);
    replacementMap.put("[field2]", "Content2_"+i);

    document.replaceWithMap(replacementMap);  //I've have this working
    finalDoc.addContentOfDoc(document);   //I don't have this working :(
}
finalDoc.saveFile("result.docx");
```

Is there a way to copy content of the `document` object to the end of the `finalDoc` object ? (there is paragraphs and tables, with styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up changing library : docx4j is way more useful for what I wanted to do.
FYI, here is the piece of code needed to append a doc at the end of another :

```
public static void append(WordprocessingMLPackage docDest, WordprocessingMLPackage docSource) {
    List<Object> objects = docSource.getMainDocumentPart().getContent();
    for(Object o : objects){
        docDest.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().add(o);
    }
}
```

This works for me, it copies the content from the docSource to the docDest, keeping the format.